# AWS Lambda Importing psycopg2 - Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda

I am trying to use the psycopg2 library with AWS lambda in my Pycharm IDE on Windows 10.

I have tried all versions of Python listed in this [repository](https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2) and I still always get the following error:

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71852778/13834264) solution where we install `aws-psycopg2` but it did not work. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56027929/13834264) solution, I have ensured that my local Python runtime and the Lambda runtime are the same and I still get the error.

I have made sure that my Python version is 64 bit as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819509/13834264) answer

Answer (score 2):

Hey incase it still didn't work, i faced the same issue here's what i did:

- ran this command:
- > pip install --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: psycopg2-binary --target psycopg-binary/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
- created a lambda layer with the above package (pyscopg-binary) and added it to the lambda function
- make sure runtimes are correct ( at first i had the lamda layer runtime 3.9 and the function 3.9, then i switched both to 3.8 and it worked)
- Im not absolutely sure aside from the runtimes which of the packages caused it to work (since i did multiple things in one step: added aws-psycopg2 to the requirements.txt in addition to changing runtime, hence im not sure if the aws-psycopg2 had anything to do with it working :), but i think that it has nothing to do with it, so it should work without it).

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by upgrading `psycopg2-binary==2.9.6` to `psycopg2-binary==2.9.9`